# Breaking a column result into further pieces and putting it in another query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

One of my result columns brings like `123/234` or `1234/45/567`. From another table we can have value of `123` as `abc`, `234` as `cde` etc. So how to get the value `abc/cde`? Please assist.

Comment: barely readable, please elaborate the post

Comment: @VaoTsun, one of my postgresql query results are like `123/567/678` or `1786/87/9`. I want to retrieve the individual values ie. `123`, `567`, `678` and retrieve their corresponding value from another table and get the combined result. For example if the value of `123`, `567` and `678` are `qwerty`, `asdfgh` and `zxcvbn`, i want to get result as `qwerty/asdfgh/zxcvbn`. i can use joins.

Comment: smth like `select unnest(string_to_array('qwerty/asdfgh/zxcvbn','/'))` to join. sorry - I still dont understandthe task...

Comment: It seems like he has row with column holding value `id/id/id` but wants to have `value/value/value` as result instead. So he would need to split those numbers (IDs) and match them with table that holds corresponding string values for them and then put it back into `value/value/value/...` with the same order.

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Do not store lists of values -- particularly numbers -- as delimited strings.  Your problem is the data structure.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add sample data and the expected output - in [tabular format](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: In one of my table, i have stored  name and respective id  In other table, I am storing the ancestry of the person i.e. great-grandfather/grandfather/father etc in another table using their ids eg. if great-grandfather Peter D’Souza’s id is 101, grandfather Thomas D’Souza’s id is 1998 and  father is Jack D’Souza’s 256 and the person name is John D’Souza, it is saved as 101/1998/256. But I am not having data for a fixed number of generations.

Comment: For some people I have data since last 3 gen and for some like 8 gen and for some if their ancestry is not known then null is saved. I want to display the results of their forefathers using their name in this format - Peter  D’Souza / Thomas  D’Souza / Jack  D’Souza / John D’Souza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to want a function that converts your id/id field into name/name value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c336/3/0